# Recommended gigabit 802.11n routers that work with DD-WRT

Tags: router, wireless-networking, hardware-rec, dd-wrt, 802.11n

I've read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/672/which-routers-do-you-prefer-for-dd-wrt-or-openwrt), and checked out [the supported devices list](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices), but am looking specifically for a gigabit 802.11n router that is easy to find and fully supported by DD-WRT.

It seems like some of the [Linksys WRT300N-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT300N_series) are a good idea, but I'm not sure which of these are easily available and fully supported.

If you think 802.11n is a waste of time, that's also an acceptable answer. Just let me know why. In that case, I'm perfectly happy to go with the standard Linksys WRT54GL.

Comment: I'd like to see this get updated now that N is a standard.

Comment: This may be a good starting point: http://www.gazaro.com/deals?q=dd-wrt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like N is still up and coming.  Possible candidates, all Linksys:

- WRT350N seems decent but a few people have had to buy a RAM heatsink to stick on the processor to prevent overheating
- WRT600N looks good but I think it's discontinued
- WRT150N is seems to have the least issues and is stable but I think it's discontinued.  This is perhaps the cheapest N router I could find. $60?
- WRT610N is a [work in progress](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=54216&highlight=reccomend+recommend+router).  The DD-WRT team is picking one apart right now to stabilize the firmware.

Finally, here's a chart just to show you what the stock firmware/hardware is capable of: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/component/option,com_chart/Itemid,189/.  If throughput is important, remember that DD-WRT does not increase speed, just adds a lot more functionality.

Comment: I'll keep this list updated w/ links and more info as I find it.

Comment: Buffalo WHR-G300N, USD 42 @ newegg, http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WHR-G300N

Comment: AirLink 101 AR670W 150Mbps 802.11n Wireless LAN/Firewall 4-Port Router , USD 30 @ buy.com, http://www.buy.com/retail/product.asp?sku=210801876&listingid=38482777

Comment: Up and coming -> Netgear WNDR3700 USD **160**. http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=350430&sid=b147dac60442b6c644ac6baae9c960a1

Comment: Netgear WNDR3300, USD 81 @ amazon. http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=27684&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

Comment: Up and coming -> Asus RT-N16. http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=59240&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0&sid=719fccc3428fb5bcfd1156dfbc7d3056 High expectations for this one, due in part to the high compatibility of Asus routers with open source firmware (WL-500Gp, WL-520Gu,Gc)

Comment: Development on the RT-N16 continues and is showing to be fairly stable, http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=61570&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=120.  At USD 100 @ newegg, it is none too cheap, but one of the few (only?) N routers that supports the DD-WRT Mega install.

Comment: Netgear WNR3500L now supported, USD **95** @ newegg.  64MB RAM, 8MB flash -> supports DD-WRT Mega!  Also a USB port (Mega install should automatically support this)

Answer (score 7):

I realize this question was asked quite a while ago...

I've had very good luck with a pair of WRT320N routers running DD-WRT.  Got them refurbished & I've been punishing both of them ever since I brought them home & loaded them with DD-WRT.

There is a [very good thread regarding DD-WRT & the WRT320N](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=387012#387012), if you go this route be sure to read it.

Also, I've noticed significant speed increases due to the 802.11n and the gigabit switch.  Sorry, I haven't done any quantitative measurements.

Answer (score 5):

There's a complete list of dd-wrt supported 802.11n devices here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices_802.11n

Answer (score 1):

Although I do think N is a waste of time the WRT54GL suffers from mediocre throughput (max 30 Mbit wan-lan). If you got a 100Mbit Internet connection you need newer gear.

I decided to go with the linksys wrt320n. It isn't supported by dd-wrt yet, but I think support will be here soon.

The reason I picked it is because it got a gigabit ethernet switch and around 100Mbit wan-lan throughput. Also the fact that I expect dd-wrt to work on it real soon now is important :)

The latest US firmware is supposedly quite good, but EU firmware is behind and there is a bug in the old (and current EU) versions that forces you to disable upnp, or your throughput will tank in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

The Linksys WRT350Nv1 (which I think is the US model) is supported, but the v2 (sold in EU and Australia) is not, as I found out when I bought one a few years ago. OpenWRT support for v2 is just about there, read [this thread](http://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=12358) for more details. It's pretty old now, so you might have trouble finding it though.

Answer (score 0):

wrt320n is now supported and seems to be a good choice.