# What's a good Wireless N router for Mac that can run opensource firmware?

Tags: router, mac

I've got a Linksys WRT54G running Tomato firmware right now, but I want to upgrade to Wireless N.  What are good routers that have opensource firmware support AND are compatible with the Mac implementation of Wireless N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Netgear WNR3500L is advertised as an "open router", where installing custom firmware is supported. More information at [MyOpenRouter.com](http://www.myopenrouter.com/). There are claims it's not really "open-source" as the source code of all components is not available (more [here](http://icrontic.com/news/netgear-responds-to-open-source-concerns-for-wnr3500l-router)).

No idea about the compatibility with the Mac implementation of Wireless N (isn't it supposed to be compatible anyway?).

Comment: I had read some reports a while back about the Wireless N implementation used by Apple wasn't compatible with some routers.  Maybe this is no longer the case.

Comment: I'm trying to keep a list of DD-WRT compatible N routers here: http://superuser.com/questions/27720/recommended-gigabit-802-11n-routers-that-work-with-dd-wrt

Answer (score 2):

linksys have released another router named wrt160n or somethink like as a linux powered router ... check their website ...

Comment: I was kind of looking for actual owner's reports but thanks.